# How to create a 'summary' cell, that aggregates unique values from a column?

Tags: excel, aggregate, summary

The closest I've been able to get is this text join:

[image: Picture of attempt]

```
 =TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, IF(MATCH(C5:C72, C5:C72, 0)=MATCH(ROW(C5:C72), ROW(C5:C72)), C5:C72, ""))
```

Is there any way to have the Cell at the top be limited to only one instance of C, R, E or D?

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that you use office365 while still needing ctrl shift enter, now unique is the real problem for you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one has the Dynamic Formula UNIQUE():

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,UNIQUE(MID(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C72),SEQUENCE(LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C72))),1)))
```

[image]

---

If not:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(MATCH(MID(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17),ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17)))),1),MID(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17),ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17)))),1),0)=ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17)))),MID(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17),ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17)))),1),""))
```

Depending on ones version this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

To order it in the order you want use this formula

Dynamic Array:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"C","R","E","D"},TEXTJOIN("",,UNIQUE(MID(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C72),SEQUENCE(LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C72))),1))))),{"C","R","E","D"},""))
```

Older version:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"C","R","E","D"},TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,IF(MATCH(MID(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17),ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17)))),1),MID(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17),ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17)))),1),0)=ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17)))),MID(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17),ROW($ZZ1:INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,C5:C17)))),1),"")))),{"C","R","E","D"},""))
```

Again depending on one's version it will require the use of Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! If I wanted to make a default/preferred order would it be possible to normalize the results in a C>R>E>D order? Also the current results are returning a 0 to the list (which may be because my table area is slightly larger than it needs to be) would it be possible to exclude the 0? 

Really happy for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you do not have a `0` somewhere in the data?  Is should skip blanks.

Comment: As, If you have `SORT()` then you can sort it `A-Z` but not a specific order.  Other wise a custom sort with formula will cause the formula to become quite large.